# input and keyboard listener

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive to remove spaces from inputs.

In this html it has several inputs.

```
      <input matInput name="id" placeholder="ID" removeSpaces />

      <input matInput name="name" placeholder="NAME"/>
```

My directive:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[removeSpaces]'
})
export class RemoveSpacesDirective {

   constructor() { }


   @HostListener('document:keydown.space', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      event.preventDefault();
   }    
}
```

It works, but it listens for both inputs, "id" and "name" this is clear because I'm using "document", so, I want to change it to input, my unsuccessful option:

```
 @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
       //problem here event is not a keyobardEvent, its an inputEvent, so, I don't have keyCode to check if its a space
      event.preventDefault();
   }
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it, it just remove "document":

```
 @HostListener('keydown.space', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   @HostListener('focus') onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
     //problem here event is not a keyobardEvent, its an inputEvent, so, I 
      don't 
     have keyCode to check if its a space
      event.preventDefault();
```

}

Comment: no, it doesnt work, it go there when focus not when keydown

Comment: @HostListener('keydown') change the focus event to keydown and try bro